# Embed and play sound (via audio element) in electron app

Tags: audio, electron, electron-builder

The actual task is to play mp3 file that should be embedded with the electron app.

I placed the mp3 file near my electron app "main.js".

I wanted to play it using some "sound-play" (https://github.com/nomadhoc/sound-play) package using bridge api, but it didn't worked out, sound is not playing.

So I want to just play it using an audio element (which seems to be more universal), but I don't get what `src` url I should supply to it. And then I wonder how to correctly add an additional asset to the built version (I'm using electron-builder).

Working with extra/local resources in election apps is kind of obscure topic for me. Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any other bundler or boilerplate with electron?

Comment: I'm using parcel, actually, I've done it so far using just it, though I wonder what would be the answer to my question, how to play resource embed with electron itself, not webapp.